# Python list difference

Tags: python, list

I am trying to find all the elements that are in list A and not in list B.

I thought something like `newList = list(set(a) & !set(b))` or `newList = list(set(a) & (not set(b)))` would work, but it's not.

If there a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do other than this?

```
newList = []
for item in a:
    if item not in b:
        newList.append(item)
```

Also important, it needs to be done in Python 2.6

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're looking for the [set difference](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set.difference):

```
newList = list(set(a).difference(b))
```

Alternatively, use the minus operator:

```
list(set(a) - set(b))
```

Comment: Note that the conversion from list -> set -> list will lose the ordering of the original list.

Answer (score 10):

Did you try

```
list(set(a) - set(b))
```

Here is a list of all [Python set operations](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set).

But this unnecessarily creates a new set for `b`. As @phihag mentions, `difference` method would prevent this.

Comment: This unnecessarily constructs a set b that you never look up in.

Comment: You're right. I didn't realize that `difference` method accepts any iterable, not just set. Edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you care about maintaining order:

```
def list_difference(a, b):
    # returns new list of items in a that are not in b
    b = set(b)
    return [x for x in a if x not in b]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> list2 = [4,5,6,7,8]
>>> print list(set(list1)-set(list2))
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: While this code may be correct, please provide some explanation.

Comment: And what it contributes to an already crowded field? :\